Usage of "around"
This is an answer that it is not correct. I am not complaining and I am finding the reason. I searched the reason to understand the answer why it is wrong but I did not find.
That is why I am asking that again.

Due to the rain, around the park is so fresh.

I need to understand why around the park is so fresh is not correct.

Grammatically there is no problem with that sentence. But semantically it is a little strange sentence. I assume you wanted to mean "the park is fresh due to rain", in that case there is no need to use "around".

Oh I see! Thank you sir @Man From India.

"Around the corner is a restaurant that my friend recently bought." This is an example sentence, where the Preposition Phrase - "around the corner" - occurs the subject position but it is not a subject. It's a locative complement.

Yes sir. I appreciate that @Man From India
